# How can I set HP iLO2 to support Active Directory Domain Name logon?

Tags: hp, ilo

We currently using default iLO 2 active directory logon schema. but we are not able to logginh using Domain name account format, John@domain.com or domain\John,

How should I set the iLO 2 that support this format?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: AFAIR, you need iLO2 Advanced to use AD login...do you have this or iLO2 Standard?

Answer (score 1):

iLO 2 supports using "@domain.com" in the search contexts
The browser has to have ActiveX enabled, and the workstation has to be logged into the domain, but the iLO 2 login page will accept Both the "john@domain" and "domain\john" forms in addition to the CN or fully qualified DN.

There's an HP whitepaper, "Configuring HP integrated Lights Out With Active Directory" that has all the details you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that username you are logging in with is the CN Attribute of the account in AD. The CN is usually the name that is displayed in AD Users and Computers for a username in the panel.

One of the quirks of AD & iLO is that it uses the CN Attribute as the username identifier rather than something that is less likely to change like the SAMAccountName attribute.

Comment: iLO 2 will accept samAccountName forms as long as the Microsoft NameTranslate ActiveX control in the login webpage is able to convert it back into an LDAP DN. Usually just means the workstation has to be a member of the domain and allowed to run ActiveX.